# Pyrogram RequestPerrButton

Tags: python, telegram, pyrogram

i want to request one of the users owned channels in pyrogram.

heres my code

```
from pyrogram.raw.types import KeyboardButtonRequestPeer, RequestPeerTypeBroadcast
from pyrogram import types

async def request_channel(message:types.Message)
     btn = [
                [
                    KeyboardButtonRequestPeer(
                        text="Select Channel",
                        button_id=1,
                        peer_type=RequestPeerTypeBroadcast(creator=True),
                    )
                ]
            ]
     keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(btn)
     
     await message.reply_text("Select your channel:", reply_markup=keyboard)
```

this raises meaningless exceptions that are all because of the keyboard.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.